# Android list view not visible

Tags: android

I have my layout xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip">
    <!-- Editext for Search -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/table_list_listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/customshape">
    </ListView>
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="@string/no_servers"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But when the activity is launched I am not able to see listview. Only Edittext is displayed.

Any help is appreaciated How can I fix this .

Comment: Are you adding any data in the `ListView` in your code through the Adapters? If there is no item to be displayed in the ListView, it won't show up

Comment: @AshishGupta this is a valid question to ask but a moot point in this situation since it still won't show with this `Layout` even if there is data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your java code, I would say it is because you haven't declared an `orientation` in your `root layout`. I am assuming that you want a vertical orientation, in which case you need in your `root layout`

```
android:orientation="vertical"`
```

By default, `LinearLayout` has a horizontal `orientation`. Since your `width` of your `EditText` is `fill_parent`, it takes up all of the width

Comment: Thats exactly what the issue was. Thank you so much